# Select a column twice with different conditions from one table and using join with two other tables

Tags: sql, inner-join

I will try to do this properly this time

So I have 3 SQL tables, Production,Resources,Asset and they look like this:

Asset:

```
ID     Name
------------
1     Line1
2     Line2
3     Line3
```

Resource:

```
ID   Asset_ID
------------
1      1
2      1
3      2
4      3
5      3
```

Production:

```
Resource_ID  Quantity    Type
------------------------------
1               5        Scrap
3               10       Scrap
1               6        Rework
3               3        Rework
1               15       Scrap
```

What I'm trying to is to get to this result:

```
Name   Scrap    Rework
-----------------------
Line1    20       6
Line2    10       3
Line3    0        0
```

Basically I need to grab each line name and then display the total scrap count and total rework count in the next two columns. Now I have done part of it, I have no problem getting what I need for either Scrap or Rework one at the time, where I get stuck is when I want to get both of them in one table in different columns.
I'm using the following right now:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Name, d.Resource_ID, SUM(d.Quantity) [Scrap]
FROM Production d inner join SubResource r ON d.Resource_ID = s.ID 
inner join Asset a ON a.ID = r.Asset_ID
WHERE Type = 'Scrap' group by a.ID, a.Name, d.Resource_ID
```

Which gives me:

```
Name   Scrap
------------
Line1    20
Line2    10
Line3    0
```

I know I need to sub-queries here(One to get scrap and one for rework) and I tried to do research on it but getting all these inner joins to work with the sub-queries confused the heck out of me.
I tried a few and I kept getting the total number of scraps and total number of reworks for ALL lines which clearly isn't correct.
I'd appreciate if someone can point me to the right direction. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional cross tab / conditional aggregation version of a `pivot()` would be like so:

```
select
    a.id
  , a.Name
  , sum(case when [Type]='Scrap' then d.Quantity else 0 end) as [Scrap]
  , sum(case when [Type]='Rework' then d.Quantity else 0 end) as [Rework]
from Asset a 
  left join Resource r 
    on a.id = r.Asset_id
  left join Production d 
      on d.Resource_id = r.id 
     and d.[Type] in ('Scrap','Rework')
group by 
    a.id
  , a.Name
```

test setup: http://rextester.com/LPMJB2638

returns:

```
+----+-------+-------+--------+
| id | Name  | Scrap | Rework |
+----+-------+-------+--------+
|  1 | Line1 |    20 |      6 |
|  2 | Line2 |    10 |      3 |
|  3 | Line3 |     0 |      0 |
+----+-------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: looking in that link when you created your table with the Type column you created it as [Type] not just Type, now how will that effect my case because in my table the column name is Type. I applied this to my code and I keep getting zero for all scrap and rework. should i use case when d.Type instead or not?

Comment: I used `[Type]` in my example because in Sql Server it is a reserved word. If you do not need to wrap `Type` in any special formatting, then do not. -- Here is an example without square brackets, but I changed the column name to `Typ` http://rextester.com/IVSU8623

Comment: got it working, changed the [Type] to Type and d.[Type] to d.Type Thanks a lot for the help.